# Join issue on SQL request

Tags: sql, oracle

My database :

```
  TB_DW_VAB_FLIGHT :  ID_TEC_FLIGHT
  TB_DW_VAB_SALES  :  QUANTITY, TRANSACTION_NUMBER, UNIT_SALES_PRICE
```

I want to have a table with 4 columns as result : CA, QTE, NB_TRANSACTION and NB_VOLS at the same month. ( N-1 )

I tried a SQL request like this :

```
    SELECT 
  sum(QUANTITY*UNIT_SALES_PRICE) as CA,
  sum(QUANTITY) as QTE,
  count(distinct TRANSACTION_NUMBER) as NB_TRANSACTION,
  count(distinct ID_TEC_FLIGHT) as NB_VOLS
FROM TB_DW_VAB_SALES, TB_DW_VAB_FLIGHT
where to_char(TB_DW_VAB_SALES.FLIGHT_DATE,'MM')=to_char(current_date,'MM')-1 and to_char(TB_DW_VAB_SALES.FLIGHT_DATE,'YYYY')=to_char(current_date,'YYYY') and SALES_TYPE='SALES'
and to_char(TB_DW_VAB_FLIGHT.FLIGHT_DATE,'MM')=to_char(current_date,'MM')-1 and to_char(TB_DW_VAB_FLIGHT.FLIGHT_DATE,'YYYY')=to_char(current_date,'YYYY');
```

But Oracle can't give me an answer.

Thank you a lot for any help.

Comment: There is no relationship between  TB_DW_VAB_FLIGHT and TB_DW_VAB_SALES. What does ID_TEC_FLIGHT tell you exactly?

Comment: There is no relation between this 2 tables, I just want to show the number of flight with a count of the number of ID ( ID_TEC_FLIGHT ) in my table TB_DW_VAB_FLIGHT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
with CTE1 as 
(
select to_char(FLIGHT_DATE, 'MM-YYYY') as PERIOD,
       sum(QUANTITY*UNIT_SALES_PRICE) as CA,
       sum(QUANTITY) as QTE,
       count(distinct TRANSACTION_NUMBER) as NB_TRANSACTION
from TB_DW_VAB_SALES
where SALES_TYPE = 'SALES'
group by to_char(FLIGHT_DATE, 'MM-YYYY')
)
, CTE2 as 
(
select count(distinct ID_TEC_FLIGHT) as NB_VOLS, 
       to_char(FLIGHT_DATE, 'MM-YYYY') as PERIOD
from TB_DW_VAB_FLIGHT
group by to_char(FLIGHT_DATE, 'MM-YYYY')
)
select CTE1.CA, 
       CTE1.QTE, 
       CTE1.NB_TRANSACTION, 
       CTE2.NB_VOLS
from CTE1
inner join CTE2 on CTE1.PERIOD = CTE2.PERIOD
where CTE1.PERIOD = to_char(add_Months(sysdate,-1),'MM-YYYY')
```

or if CTE's are not available in your software:

```
select CTE1.CA, 
       CTE1.QTE, 
       CTE1.NB_TRANSACTION, 
       CTE2.NB_VOLS
from 
(
select to_char(FLIGHT_DATE, 'MM-YYYY') as PERIOD,
       sum(QUANTITY*UNIT_SALES_PRICE) as CA,
       sum(QUANTITY) as QTE,
       count(distinct TRANSACTION_NUMBER) as NB_TRANSACTION
from TB_DW_VAB_SALES
where SALES_TYPE = 'SALES'
group by to_char(FLIGHT_DATE, 'MM-YYYY')
) CTE1
inner join 
(
select count(distinct ID_TEC_FLIGHT) as NB_VOLS, 
       to_char(FLIGHT_DATE, 'MM-YYYY') as PERIOD
from TB_DW_VAB_FLIGHT
group by to_char(FLIGHT_DATE, 'MM-YYYY')
) CTE2 
    on CTE1.PERIOD = CTE2.PERIOD
where CTE1.PERIOD = to_char(add_Months(sysdate,-1),'MM-YYYY')
```

Comment: @AlexPoole He has since updated the original post... Editing now

Comment: Hi back, 
This request works fine in Oracle but JasperSoft doesn't wan't build "with". There is a possibility to get a similar request in classic SQL ?

Comment: It works. You make my day, thank you again ..
Have a nice day !